# How to get Facebook User Access-token on Server Side by using Username and Password?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible that I take the user's facebook credentials and sign in using my server side code and get the access token.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want a user to give you their facebook credentials and why would a user want to do that? It poses a security risk. The whole point of access tokens is to avoid this. You would want them to connect to your app via Facebook and that's how you get an access token. Have you read the docs?https://developers.facebook.com/products/login/

Comment: And to add. It is not possible to get an access token from a username and password.